# ng-Grid Overlapping with bootstrap drop down

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a angular js grid with a drop down button at the header.
But the angular ng grid is somehow overlapping the dropdown button options.
Here is the [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TOhDhRYM74k3Qevb57wT?p=preview)

I am trying to see the Gender Select Dropdown.

But the Drop down menu is not available to the user

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: It seems like your Gender Select Dropdown doesn't even work by itself, see this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/XhZrIL5aUvRDFFzcnyIT?p=preview)

Comment: @yes Sorry JoseM.. I tried to replicate my local project there...  can you please correct it? just a basic Drop Down? Please ...